# reactjs redux Actions must be plain objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have a problem "**Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.**"

I'm using reactjs with this boilerplate (https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/)
I waste 1 day to fix this problem, but no result. I was trying move fetch request to action (without saga) and result the same.

*My component:*

```
...
import { compose } from 'redux';
import injectReducer from 'utils/injectReducer';
import injectSaga from 'utils/injectSaga';
import { successFetching } from './actions';
import reducer from './reducers';
import saga from './saga';

class NewsListPage extends React.PureComponent {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(saga())
  }

  ...
};

NewsListPage.propTypes = {
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  isSuccess: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  items: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

const selector = (state) => state;

const mapStateToProps = createSelector(
  selector,
  (isFetching, isSuccess, items) => ({ isFetching, isSuccess,items })
);

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
  };
}
const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'NewsList', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'NewsList', saga });
const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default compose(
    withReducer,
    withSaga,
    withConnect
  )(NewsListPage);
```

*My actions:*

```
export const NEWS_FETCH_LOADING = 'NEWS_FETCH_LOADING';
export const NEWS_FETCH_FAILURE = 'NEWS_FETCH_FAILURE';
export const NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS = 'NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS';

export function preFetching() {
  return {
    type: NEWS_FETCH_LOADING,
  }
}

export function successFetching(json) {
  return {
    type: NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS,
    payload: json
  }
}

export function failureFetching(error) {
  return {
    type: NEWS_FETCH_FAILURE,
    payload: error
  }
}
```

*My reducers:*

```
...
import { NEWS_FETCH_LOADING, NEWS_FETCH_FAILURE, NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS } from './actions'

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  isFetching: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  items: []
};

function NewsListReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEWS_FETCH_LOADING:
    case NEWS_FETCH_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        isSuccess: false
      })
    case NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        isSuccess: true,
        items: action.payload,
      })
    default:
      return Object.assign({}, state)
  }
}

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  NewsListReducer
})
export default rootReducer
```

*My saga:*

```
import { call, put, select, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {NEWS_FETCH_LOADING, NEWS_FETCH_FAILURE, NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS, preFetching, successFetching, failureFetching} from './actions';
import request from 'utils/request';

export function* getNews() {
  const requestURL ='%MY_URL%';

  try {
    const req = yield call(request, requestURL);
    yield put(successFetching(req));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(failureFetching(err));
  }
}

export default function* NewsListSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS, getNews);
}
```

**EDIT:**
@Alleo Indong, i tried your advice and its almost work.

I change in component mapDispatchToProps to

```
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    getData: () => dispatch(loadNews()),
  };
}
```

And add new function to actions.js

```
export function loadNews() {
  return {
    type: NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS,
  }
}
```

**But now ajax sent every seconds** like in while cycle. I tried call `this.props.getData();` in `componentDidMount` and in `constructor`and result same.

**EDIT 2**
In component i add

```
import * as  actionCreators from './actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
```

In constructor i change

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const {dispatch} = this.props;

  this.boundActionCreators = bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch)
}
```

But here `dispatch` is undefined and in `componentDidMount` too.
And change `mapDispatchToProps` to

```
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    ...bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch),
  };
}
```

Comment: Hello @AND the problem here is because you are dispatching the wrong thing, you have to put your actions inside `mapDispatchToProps` and dispatch those actionCreators instead of the saga which returns a `generator function`

Comment: Hi @AND please check my answer :) you are still doing something wrong, when you use `bindActionCreators` onto your `mapDispatchToProps` you dont need to bind it inside `constructor` anymore, you can just call it in the `props`

Comment: @Alleo Indong thank your for your help. Now all work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @AND and welcome to stackoverflow! As I mentioned in the comment on the main post, you are dispatching a GENERATOR instead of an object on your

`dispatch(saga());`

Here's an example to help you

On your component import the actions that you want to use like this.

```
import * actionCreators from './actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
```

Learn more about bindActionCreators here [enter link description here](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators)

This will import all of the exported actionCreators that you created there.
In my opinion you don't need `successFetching` and `failureFetching` anymore as you can dispatch this actions later on on your saga

Then in your `mapDispatchToProps` you would want to register this actioncreator

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        ...bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch),
    };
}
```

Then on your saga, I want to point up some problems here as well.
First your function

```
export default function* NewsListSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS, getNews);
}
```

Is actually what we call a `watcher` where it watch when a certain action was dispatch, in this function you are already waiting for the `NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS` before `getNews` is called which is wrong, because you first have do the `FETCHING` before you will know if it is failed or success so yeah this function should be like this

```
export default function* NewsListSaga() {
    yield takeLatest(NEWS_FETCH_LOADING, getNews);
}
```

This simple means that you will `take all the latest`NEWS_FETCH_LOADING`actions that was dispatched and will call the`getNews`.

then on your `getNews` generator function, you can do it like this

```
export function* getNews() {
    const requestURL ='%MY_URL%';

    try {
        const req = yield call(request, requestURL);
        yield put({type: NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS, req});
    } catch (err) {
        yield put({type: NEWS_FETCH_FAILED, err});
    }
}
```

in here

```
const req = yield call(request, requestURL);
```

You are saying that you will wait for the result of the request / service that you called, it might be a promise.

Then in here, this is why you won't need the functions `successFetching` and `failureFetching` functions anymore, since you can do it like this

`yield put({type: NEWS_FETCH_SUCCESS, req});`

One last important step that you have to do now is to call the actionCreator inside your `componentDidMount()`

like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { preFetching } = this.props;
    preFetching();
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I have some questions. 
1. How i understand in `actions.js`  i need comment all functions?
2. In component `const {dispatch} = this.props;` is undefined. How i understand to call fetch i need write `dispatch(actionCreators.loadNews())`

If you need

Comment: @AND you only need to retain the function `preFetching` on your actions and call it inside your component like this `this.props.preFetching()`

Comment: Note that you can simplify this by using the "object shorthand" syntax supported by `connect`.  Just pass the object full of action creators directly as the second argument instead of writing an actual `mapDispatch` function, like : `export default connect(mapState, actionCreators)(MyComponent).  There's almost never a good reason to write a separate `mapDispatch` function.